# ispell-init-process: Error: The encoding "nil" is not known

Tags: doom, ispell

### ispell-init-process fails

When I try to correct a word with ispell, I got the following error:

```
ispell-init-process: Error: The encoding "nil" is not known. This could also mean that the file "/nix/store/pj0ivrsxk2hik5hv7pdywdxxga0m1wvv-aspell-0.60.8/lib/aspell/nil.cset" could not be opened for reading or does not exist.
```

I dug into this a bit. `ispell-init-process` internally sets variable `ispell-library-directory`

```
        (setq ispell-library-directory (ispell-check-version)
              ;; Assign a non-nil value to ispell-process-directory
              ;; before calling ispell-start-process, since that
              ;; function needs it to set default-directory when
              ;; ispell-async-processp is nil.
          ispell-process-directory default-directory
          ispell-process (ispell-start-process)
          ispell-filter nil
          ispell-filter-continue nil)
```

[The full source code here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/640fd9b594fa376e6493efbe0cf083e1270ddd3f/lisp/textmodes/ispell.el#L1260)

and I confirmed that this is indeed `nil` on my Emacs.

I guess this is because `(ispell-check-version)` returns `nil`. But I don't have a good idea why that happens.
Could someone give me pointers, or any idea why this happens?

[The definition of (ispell-check-version) here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/640fd9b594fa376e6493efbe0cf083e1270ddd3f/lisp/textmodes/ispell.el#L639)

### Some more info

1. `aspell` exists in the $PATH and Emacs can see it

```
(executable-find "aspell") => "/nix/store/lzphgp0k1cm7sz27f59jqaa57r13mlc2-aspell-env/bin/aspell"
```

2. `aspell` version seems correct:

```
$ aspell -vv
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.8)
```

3. Dictionaries seem available

```
$ aspell dump dicts
en
...
en_US
...
```

4. I'm using DoomEmacs `doom/version` below:

```
GNU Emacs     v28.2            nil
Doom core     v3.0.0-pre       HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD b66ad7703 2023-03-17 00:33:32 -0400
Doom modules  v23.03.0-pre     HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD b66ad7703 2023-03-17 00:33:32 -0400
```

Comment: In my setup (using aspel 0.60.8 as well), my `ispell-library-directory` is also `nil` and `(ispell-check-version)` returns `nil` and yet I don't have any problem checking a word.

Comment: That's good to know! Indeed I found that `ispell-library-directory` does not need to be set if `ispell-async-processp` is non-nil.

Comment: @NickD Could you also tell me what you get when you evaluate `(ispell-get-coding-system)`? I got `nil` and am wondering if that's the issue.

Comment: I get `utf-8`, coming from `(assoc ispell-current-dictionary ispell-dictionary-alist)` which returns `(nil "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-B") nil utf-8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually just adding this to a config file (In my case `~/.doom.d/config.el`) solved it.

```
(after! ispell
  (setq ispell-dictionary "en_US")
  (setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_US")
  (setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
        '(("en_US" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_US") nil utf-8)
          )))
```

I was expecting either `ispell-dictionary` or `ispell-local-dictionary-alist` to be set automatically.